# Teamcity: Update local maven repository on build server from Nexus

Tags: maven, teamcity, nexus, dependency-management

I am using **Teamcity** to build by **Maven based Java Project**.

I have recently added a third party artifact into my Nexus Repository Manager. Now when I am building the project, I am getting the following error:

```
[core:project1] Failed to execute goal on project project1: Could not resolve dependencies for project core:project1:jar:1.0.0: Failure to find com.oracle:ojdbc:jar:11.2.0.2.0 in http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
```

Can anyone tell me how can i **FORCE** updates in the local repository cache on my build server? Is this something to do with Maven `settings.xml` ?

Answer (score 3):

Try running maven with with the **-U** option.

http://www.sonatype.com/books/mvnref-book/reference/running.html#running-sect-deps-option

Answer (score 1):

I think, that your real trouble was that the public group (nexus) 
wasn't aggregating artifacts from third party.

The solution was to add a repository for third party artifacts to
`settings.xml` or to make a different group that will also provide
yours third party artifacts.